# How to write an email to request a dataset to a professor

Tags: etiquette, email, writing-style, communication

I'm interested in a dataset used in a scientific article, but I am not able to find this dataset on the Internet, I guess it is because the dataset was provided by NSTAR (an energy company) that no longer exists (it has merged with Eversource).

I have thought of requesting it to the corresponding author of the article, but I have never sent anything to a MIT visitant professor (female, just for the record) and I have never called a teacher of mine by its title. I think that there is not such a strict culture in Spain of calling everyone by its title. Can anyone help me in writing the letter? Will it bother her if I send such request? How should I start? What should I say about myself? How should I end the letter?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Professors are just normal humans, even at MIT. Be friendly and brief. How about this:

### Subject:

> Request for dataset used in [article name]

### Body:

> Dear Professor [last name],
>
> on page [page number] of the article "[article name]" you are referring to a dataset consisting of [elements of dataset]. I am currently working on _____ and would like to ask if you could send me this dataset for further analysis as it would help me [benefit for you, e.g. "verify your results"].
>
> Thank you,
>
> [your first name] [your last name]

Comment: Nice answer. My only suggestion would be to use the correct title: either _Dr._ or _Professor_ last name.

Comment: @RichardErickson Was about to make the same suggestion! Definitely use the correct title (I recommend _Dr._ if you're unsure of their professorship standing).

Comment: I assumed that most people in academia don't really care about their academic titles when it comes to day to day communication and that they are only used in very formal communication.

Comment: After reconsideration I agree with your suggestions. It is more safe and reduces the risk of offending her by not showing enough respect. I changed my proposal.

Comment: @problemofficer If you wish to be informal, avoid the use of any title and use the [first name]. However, using the wrong (i.e., "Ms" in this case) would be insulting. My personal rule of thumb for academic writing is to be formal unless indicated otherwise.

Comment: @problemofficer My bad... I have sent the email with my personal email account instead of my academic one... Do u think that it can be a problem?

Comment: @vicaba: It think, it will probably make a difference since a university domain gives you more prestige and trustworthiness, but I don't think that it is going to be a problem. It is just research data after all.